# Can anyone explain why these creases occur on my model?

Tags: modifiers

[image][image]

Hi, been having trouble sorting this out used a boolean modifier and cant seem to find a why a to resolve this. Not undertsanding why this is happening.

Thanks

Comment: It's usually caused by bad topology but without seeing the Blend file (https://blend-exchange.com/) or at least an image of it in Edit mode it's difficult to help further.

Comment: hi, thanks I uploaded a picture of it in edit mode.

Comment: Those happen because your topology is not great. Very common problem, especially when booleans are used, but basically impossible to explain and help fix with a text answer. I'd recommend searching videos for "hardsurface shading problems" etc.

Comment: maybe we can try to find a quick fix, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/